# Why table data is not passed to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I was trying to login to a site (based on apache2 mysql-server php5-mysql php5 libapache2-mod-php5 ) from a local host . It was a docker project.When i start the container , i am able to access the login page,but I cannot access it with username and password.

When I am trying to display the databases and tables ,it shows all of them,but for the query to display table data,it gives empty set as the output. But when I access the Project code,MySQL file hold the data .What is causing this problem. How to rectify it?

I am running docker inside Ubuntu distro on WSL2 windows 10.

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS` to see if there's any data to actually load.

Comment: For row status it displays 0,but for data length it displays 16384 @tadman

Comment: That's effectively the minimum size you'll ever see. It means there's nothing in it.

Comment: But on MySQL file inside project it holds the data @tadman

Comment: Check the `Auto_increment` column to see i you have any data at all. You may not. You might need to restore from a dump.

Comment: for some of the table it shows null values,but rest of them shows values @tadman

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by "You might need to restore from a dump" @tadman

Comment: Where is this data supposed to come from? Is this an application you're trying to deploy, or one that's *been* deployed and now you're trying to get data from it?

Comment: @tadman I was trying to be a part of a project for college login ,I  cloned the repository.As i am a beginner,i just wanted to look ,how everything works,and then this error came up .When I look in the project file ,all the database names are being shown in the MySQL server but not the data. I appreciate that you are replying back,thanks